# Matplotlib - animate PIL images in Jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

How can I create an animation in Jupyter using PIL images?

I'm creating drawings with PIL. Here is the code for one frame (other frames are generated by just increasing theta)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

width, height = 800,800
theta = math.pi / 3
image = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

# draw sun
sun_radius = 80
center_x = width/2
center_y = width/2
draw.ellipse(
    (
        center_x - sun_radius/2, 
        center_y - sun_radius/2, 
        center_x + sun_radius/2, 
        center_y + sun_radius/2
    ), 
    fill = 'yellow', outline ='orange'
)

# draw planet
planet_radius = 20
orbit_radius = 300
planet_offset_x = center_x + math.cos(theta) * orbit_radius
planet_offset_y = center_y + math.sin(theta) * orbit_radius
draw.ellipse(
    (
        planet_offset_x - planet_radius/2, 
        planet_offset_y - planet_radius/2, 
        planet_offset_x + planet_radius/2, 
        planet_offset_y + planet_radius/2
    ), 
    fill = 'blue', outline ='blue'
)

plt.imshow(image)
```

This the frame that the above code generates
[image]

---

I already have a solution, I'm posting this because it took me a while to get working and I think it will be useful to others

Answer (score 1):

I would advocate for doing the whole animation in matplotlib directly, since that is more memory efficient (no need to create store 100 images) and gives a better graphics quality (because pixels would not need to resampled).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from IPython.display import HTML


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

width, height = 800,800
planet_radius = 20
orbit_radius = 300
sun_radius = 80
center_x = width/2
center_y = width/2


ax.axis([0,width,0,height])
ax.set_aspect("equal")

sun = Circle((center_x,center_y), radius=sun_radius,
             facecolor="yellow", edgecolor="orange")
ax.add_patch(sun)


def get_planet_offset(theta):
    x = center_x + np.cos(theta) * orbit_radius
    y = center_y + np.sin(theta) * orbit_radius
    return x,y

planet = Circle(get_planet_offset(0), radius=planet_radius,
                 color="blue")
ax.add_patch(planet)

def update(theta):
    planet.center = get_planet_offset(theta)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100), 
                              interval=50, repeat_delay=1000)
HTML(ani.to_html5_video())
```

[image]

Comment: Is it still possible to do this with PIL images? For this case it works well, but I have more complicated animations to deal with later

Comment: The whole point here is not to use PIL at all. Now that may in that sense not answer the question, but for the problem at hand, namely to animate some shapes on screen, this is an easier solution. Feel free to point me to a more complicated case, for which you would need PIL images

Answer (score 0):

Use matplotlib's ArtistAnimation and to_html5_video(). Relevant sources

- [Matplotlib ArtistAnimation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/dynamic_image.html)
- [Embed Matplotlib Animations in Jupyter](http://louistiao.me/posts/notebooks/embedding-matplotlib-animations-in-jupyter-as-interactive-javascript-widgets/)

[image]

This solution requires installing ffmpeg (and imagemagick if saving a gif). A simple way to install both is to just install [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php) with the "legacy" and "ffmpeg" options (cross platform, easy `exe` install for windows)

```
import numpy as np
import math

from matplotlib import animation, rc
from IPython.display import HTML
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

fig = plt.figure()

width, height = 800,800
images = []
for theta in np.linspace(0, 2 * math.pi, 100):
    image = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

    # draw sun
    sun_radius = 80
    center_x = width/2
    center_y = width/2
    draw.ellipse(
        (
            center_x - sun_radius/2, 
            center_y - sun_radius/2, 
            center_x + sun_radius/2, 
            center_y + sun_radius/2
        ), 
        fill = 'yellow', outline ='orange'
    )

    # draw planet
    planet_radius = 20
    orbit_radius = 300
    planet_offset_x = center_x + math.cos(theta) * orbit_radius
    planet_offset_y = center_y + math.sin(theta) * orbit_radius
    draw.ellipse(
        (
            planet_offset_x - planet_radius/2, 
            planet_offset_y - planet_radius/2, 
            planet_offset_x + planet_radius/2, 
            planet_offset_y + planet_radius/2
        ), 
        fill = 'blue', outline ='blue'
    )
    im = plt.imshow(image, animated=True)
    images.append([im])

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, images, interval=50, blit=True, repeat_delay=1000)
HTML(ani.to_html5_video())
```